# Вимова вголос адрес веб-сайтів

Tags: фонетика

Чи є якість поради/вказівки стосовно вимови адрес веб-ресурсів (наприклад, реклама інтернет-крамниць на радіо чи по ТБ, диктовка по телефону)?

Приклади:

- `rada.gov.ua`: чи диктуються знаки пунктуації ("рада крапка гов крапка юа")?
- `www.pravopys.net`: "ве ве ве" чи "дабл ю дабл ю дабл ю" чи "потрійне дабл ю" (російською ще чула "даби даби даби")?

Comment: Для людей, які знайомі з інтернетом, однаково, чи ви кажете "ве ве ве", чи "дабл ю дабл ю дабл ю", чи "потрійне дабл ю", чи "дабі дабі дабі". А от "крапка" треба казати, це важливо. А ".ua" кажуть або "ю ей", або "у а", змішувати не варто, треба бути послідовним.

Comment: Я якраз українською (на ICTV, здається) чув «дабі-дабі-дабі́», а російською такого не чув.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Коректно говорити `дабл-ю, дабл-ю, дабл-ю`, `потрійне дабл-ю` або `три дабл-ю` і промовляти `крапка`.**

Google Translate підтверджує такий [варіант](https://translate.google.com/#uk/ru/www.data.gov.ua):

```
www.data.gov.ua 
[дабл-ю, дабл-ю, дабл-ю, крапка, дата, крапка, гов, крапка, юей]
```

Керуючись виключно економічними факторами - для зменшення тривалості реклами (а, відповідно, і вартості, оскільки зазвичай тарифікується кожна секунда) замість `дабл-ю, дабл-ю, дабл-ю` використовують скорочені варіанти: `дабі, дабі, дабі`, `потрійне дабл-ю`, `три дабл-ю`.

Окремо потрібно зупинитись на `дабі, дабі, дабі` та його похідних. `Дабл-ю` не хочуть вимовляти не лише українці, а й англомовні користувачі інтернету. Як свідчать електронні словники сленгу англійської мови, частину адреси `www` вимовляють як `даб-даб-даб`. Тобто, як і в англійській мові, українське `дабі-дабі-дабі` — типова сленгова форма, яка, на жаль, часто звучить на радіо й телебаченні.

Comment: Висновок: зробіть свій сайт доступним без www і зекономте на рекламі! :)